# Can't use fopen and mkdir in same program

Tags: c, file, syntax, fopen, mkdir

I'm working on creating files with valid syntax possibilities that can be compiled later. I started by using the fopen method to create files, and then I added the mkdir() function to handle file creation. However, I've run into a peculiar issue where I can't use both functions together in the same program. The compiler seems to prefer executing only the fopen function. It's worth noting that both functions work fine individually. Can you help me understand why this is happening?

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fprt;
    char *filename = "File";

    fprt = fopen(filename,"w");

    if (!fprt ) // equivalent to saying if ( in_file == NULL )
             { 
                printf("oops, file can't be read\n");
             }


    mkdir(filename,0777);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: On Windows you can't make a folder with the same name as a file already there.

Comment: delete the file first, before attempting to create a directory with the same name: `if (remove(filename)) { /* perror ... */ }`

Comment: So, are you saying that on a Mac you can make a folder with the same name as a file already there?

Comment: @WeatherVane no, it doesn't allow. It's same on Mac.

Comment: So, use a different name.

Comment: What exactly do you think `mkdir` does? In the text of your question, you said something about "handle file creation". Which `mkdir` does not. `mkdir`, as its name suggests, is for making directories.

Comment: (Side note: the compiler couldn't care less about this. You coded a call to functions, that are defined in a library. The compiler generate a program that calls those functions of those libraries. Its job is done. It has no idea what those functions are. And whether those functions do what they are supposed to do is their problem, not its)

Comment: When describing a problem in the future, always state what the observed behavior of the program is and what the expected behavior is. Nowhere in this post did you say what the program is doing that you do not want it to do or vice-versa. This was a simple question, so readers can guess what the issue is, but this is a skill you need to practice and develop to communicate with colleagues in the future.

Comment: As you checked the return value from `fopen()` you should do the same with`mkdir()`, eg `if (mkdir(filename, 0777)) { /* perror ... */ }`

Comment: and how can I put the file inside the folder please ?

Comment: How many different ways can you think of for creating a file in a newly created directory?  And which functions are you allowed to use?  With POSIX, you could use open(), openat(), or creat(), with help from chdir() if desired. Or you can use fopen().  Fundamentally, you need to give the function that creates the file a name that refers to the file in the directory.  For example, concatenate the directory name, a slash and the filename.  Or change directory to the new directory and then create the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** use `fopen` and `mkdir` in the same program.

You **can't** create a folder and a file with the same name at the same location.

You encountered the latter as a problem and misunderstood it, thinking the former. `mkdir` creates a folder, it stands for

> make directory

and you will not be able to create a file with it. So, what you likely wanted is to create a directory and then create a file into it. But then you will need to create the directory first and THEN the file and, make sure that the path of the file you create contains the directory you want it to be created into.